# Loading a link in the same page in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a functionality wherein i must load a chart on clicking an option in the same page with the options remaining on the left without disappearing. My web page design will be look like the one attached below. Now ,say , if i select the fly option sub-item , i must have the page loading in same page.

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href='some link' target="_self"><span>Sub item</span></a>
</li>
```

So I have tried by mentioning 'target='_self'' but this makes the options on the left to disappear? So how do i accomplish it?

[image]

Comment: You may need to divide your html into sub sections and load the required url into particular section using iframe.

Comment: what do you mean it disappears? if you click the menu item you go to a different site and on that page you need to show the menu again.

Comment: @qxxx: i need the menu to be shown in the same page even after loading the link

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying `target` attribute, link will open in either same window / new window / new tab. So you have to have all options from left displayed in new page.

Better use jQuery `$('destinationSelector').load('pageurl .someElementContent')` to dynamically load content on click.

Comment: I am not much aware of using jquery. Anyway, i will try out.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a single page application.Make your website using some js framework,backboneJS,angular,ember.

or trying shortcut,
Try making use of ajax,make a ajax call and replace the contents.

Comment: I am just starting out with html and so i guess it will take time for me to get my hands on using js frameworks. Having said that, please suggest me a simple solution

Comment: Ok so the idea is,have your contents in some html file,files could be separate according to the contents,on click of link make a ajax call and then load that fetched content in some div or body.

Go through JQUERY load and ajax.
leave a comment if you want more help

Comment: It does give me an idea on how to get about doin it!! ll ask f i need help.. thanks!!